# How to zoom in and out the user presp

Tags: customization, makehuman

I am on Mac with Blender 2.71. I got an mhx file imported. But the problem is that it looks huge. I could see only the bottom part in user presp.

In File -> User Pref -> Input, Presets set to Maya.

How could I Zoom in and Out so that I could see the whole object (Exported Human Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all objects in the scene:

- in the 3D Viewport footer: : View -> View all
- or press <kbd>Home</kbd>

If you have a mouse with a mouse wheel:

- Scroll with the wheel.
- Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> then as long as you keep the the key and the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> pressed, you can zoom in/out by dragging the mouse.

If you have a 2 button mouse:

- Open user preferences
- Open the Input Tab
- enable *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*
- then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> then click <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> and drag the mouse to zoom in/out