# How to change camera view size

Tags: camera

beginner here. Somehow I managed to reduce the camera view to this little square. How can I make it so the bounds are bigger? I've tried changing render dimensions,  focal length and camera sensor size, but this seems to only change the ratio. Simply scaling the camera does not work either.

Thnx

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the size of the camera view?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42275/can-i-change-the-size-of-the-camera-view) or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/how-to-increase-camera-frames-view-area/44264#44264

Comment: ... or move the camera backward

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16222/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-the-user-presp/16223#16223

Comment: Lemon: tried it, doesn't do what i need
Cegaton: thank you for the links ! They are what i need! I'm sorry I didn't find them

Answer (score 0):

Home key for best fit, works for all panels.
Scroll up or down to adjust at your convenience.

Comment: That actually doesn't anything to the camera view.

Comment: But this was what I needed! Super! Thank you